# Identity involving a quadratic term inside the Pochhammer symbol

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, combinatorial-identities

This identity came up in my research:
$$
\sum_{m=1}^n m^2 \frac{(\frac{xy}n + m-1)_{2m-1} (n+m-1)_{2m-1}}{(x+m)_{2m+1} (y+m)_{2m+1}} = \frac{n^2}{(x^2-n^2) (y^2 - n^2)}.
$$
Here $n$ is a fixed positive integer and $x,y$ are variables. So for each $n$ this is an identity of rational functions in $x,y$. I denote by $(x)_n$ the falling factorial (Pochhammer symbol)
$$
(x)_n = x(x-1)\cdots (x-n+1).
$$
It may be worth pointing out that all the falling factorials that appear are of this form:
$$
(x+m-1)_{2m-1} = x \prod_{i=1}^{m-1} (x^2-i^2)
$$
This identity looked very foreign to me because of the quadratic argument $\frac{xy}n$ inside the falling factorial. I managed to prove it eventually, but I wonder if there is a simple/standard approach or if this is known and/or related to something interesting.

EDIT: If you prefer binomial identities, by taking the partial fraction expansions this reduces to
$$
\sum_{m=\max(a,b)}^n \binom{2m}{m-a} \binom{2m}{m-b} \binom{\frac{ab}{n}+m-1}{2m-1} \binom{n+m-1}{2m-1} = 0
$$
for positive integers $a,b,n$ satisfying $a<n, b<n$.

Comment: Hi Anton! Can't you multiply both sides by $x-n$, then set $x=n$ so get a one variable identity where you now multiply by $y-n$ and set $y=n$ ? I didn't do the computation but I expect it will work.

Comment: Hi Henri! But it is not enough to check the pole at $x=n$. You should also prove that other poles cancel out.

Comment: I'll write the idea of my solution here (I didn't want to write it in the post as it might discourage people to try to find their own solution): We induct on $n$. Then for $k<n$ and $x,y$ satisfying $xy=\pm kn$ the identity holds by the induction assumption. Thus the numerator of the difference of the LHS and RHS is divisible by $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (x^2 y^2 - k^2 n^2)$ so its degree is at least $4n−4$. On the other hand, it is at most $4n-8$ because the denominator must divide $\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} (x^2-i^2) (y^2-i^2)$ which has degree $4n-4$ and the degree of the numerator is less by 4.

Comment: Nice proof, indeed forgot other poles.

Comment: There is a theorem of Wilf and Zeilberger that all such (whatever this means) identities are actually telescoping (that is, if $\sum_k F(n,k)\equiv 0$ for some $F$, then the reason is that $F(n+1,k)-F(n,k)=G(n,k+1)-G(n,k)$ for some $G$).

Comment: @Fedor I'm puzzled about how to apply this here, what are $n,k$ and how do these functions depend on the remaining variables. If I just try to apply this naively I may end up in a situation where I can prove the identity for each fixed pair $x,y$, but different pairs require different proofs.

Comment: Anton, $n$ is your $n$, $k$ is your $m$ (traditional notation for it is $k$), other variables are, say, parameters or constants.

Comment: @Fedor but then how do you know you don't run into the problem that you will have to construct different proofs for different values of $x,y$? You see, the terms are indeed hypergeometric for fixed integer values of $x,y$ (assuming you replaced $x$ and $y$ by $nx, ny$), but the degree of the rational function depends on $x$, $y$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov This isn't quite true. The WZ method, $$(+1,)−(,)=(,+1)−(,),$$ usually works, but not always. What always works is Zeilberger's algorithm, which is a little more complicated. See Theorem 6.2.1 of $A=B$. (https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/Downld.html)

Comment: Whenever a sum $\sum_{m=1}^n t(n,m)$ with weird looking parameters has a nice closed form, it's a good bet that the indefinite sum $\sum_{m=1}^k t(n,m)$ also has a closed form. (This is almost always the case with Putnam problems!) Tewodros's solution shows that this is the case here; we don't need creative telescoping, just indefinite summation, which Maple (for example) can do easily. This also shows that the identity can easily be greatly generalized, though it would take a bit of work to find which specializations of the most general form are nice.

Comment: The original sum (with $x$ and $y$, falling factorials) is also indefinitely summable, according to Maple.

Comment: Indeed, the original sum from $m$ to $\infty$ turns out to be $\frac{(\frac{xy}{n}+m-1)_{2m-1} (n+m-1)_{2m-1}}{(x+m-1)_{2m-1} (y+m-1)_{2m-1}} \frac{n^2}{(x^2-n^2)(y^2-n^2)}$, easily shown by induction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your identity is not just a curiosity. It is a special case of a result that has been used to obtain many quadratic and cubic identities for hypergeometric series. Perhaps the most general formulation is given by Warnaar (Summation and transformation formulas for elliptic hypergeometric series, Constr. Approx. 18 (2002), 479–502, Lemma 3.1). There it is formulated as a theta function identity. In the rational limit case, when one replaces a Jacobi theta function $\theta(x|\tau)$ by $x$, it becomes
\begin{multline*}\sum_{k=0}^n (a_k^2-b_k^2)(c_k^2-d_k^2)\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(a_j^2-c_j^2)(b_j^2-d_j^2)
\prod_{j=k+1}^n(a_j^2-d_j^2)(b_j^2-c_j^2)\\=
\prod_{j=0}^n(a_j^2-c_j^2)(b_j^2-d_j^2)-
\prod_{j=0}^n(a_j^2-d_j^2)(b_j^2-c_j^2).
\end{multline*}
Here, $a_j$, $b_j$, $c_j$ and $d_j$ are arbitrary sequences. Your identity seems to be the case $a_j=x$, $b_j=n+1$, $c_j=(n+1)(j+1)/y$, $d_j=j+1$. Since $d_n=b_j$, the first term on the right-hand side vanishes. Of course you also need to replace $n$ by $n-1$ and $k$ by $m-1$.

As Ira Gessel points out, this is an indefinite summation, so once you guess the identity the proof is trivial by induction on $n$.

(I removed my claim that there are typos in your formula. I missed that you use falling rather than rising factorials.)

Answer (score 7):

This is an expansion on the [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410096/identity-involving-a-quadratic-term-inside-the-pochhammer-symbol#comment1052242_410096) by Fedor Petrov on the Wilf–Zeilberger method in proving the identity
$$\sum_{m=\max(a,b)}^n \binom{2m}{m-a} \binom{2m}{m-b} \binom{\frac{ab}{n}+m-1}{2m-1} \binom{n+m-1}{2m-1} = 0. \label{1}\tag1$$
Denote $\Theta=\frac{ab}n$. Define the two functions $G(n,m):=F(n,m)\cdot R(n,m)$ and
$$F(n,m):=\binom{2m}{m-a} \binom{2m}{m-b} \binom{\Theta+ m-1}{2m-1} \binom{n+m-1}{2m-1} \qquad \text{where}$$
$$R(n,m):=
-\frac{(m^2-a^2)(m^2-b^2)\,n^2}{(n^2-b^2)(n^2-a^2)\,m^2}.$$
Then, a routine check shows that $F(n,m)=G(n,m+1)-G(n,m)$. Summing over all integers $m$, the right-hand side vanishes. That means,
$$\sum_mF(n,m)=0$$
as desired in equation \eqref{1}. $\,\,\square$.